# Find x so that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\frac{1}{(x-1)^n\sqrt{n+5}}}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to get find the $x$ values that make this series converge (simply and absolutely):

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\frac{1}{(x-1)^n\sqrt{n+5}}}$$

First I study the absolute convergence by using an absolute value:

$$\left|{{\frac{1}{(x-1)^n\sqrt{n+5}}}}\right|$$

We get a positive series so I can now use the root test (this is because we have a root of $n$ so I would like to get rid of it) and I get:

$$\left|{{\frac{1}{(x-1)\sqrt[2n]{n+5}}}}\right|=\dots$$

I don't really know what to do here. Also, I'm not sure if I have to use the Cauchy criterion for series every time I want to test the convergence of a series. Any hints?

Comment: Take the limit. What condition on the limit would make the series converges absolutely?

Comment: @xbh I'm not sure.

Comment: I was actually talking about how to use the root test. Nevermind. My direction is not explicit for you, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By root test, since for any polynomial $p(n)$ we have that $\sqrt[n]{p(n)} \to 1$, we obtain

$$\left|{{\frac{1}{x-1}}}\right|{{\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt[n]{(n+5)}\right)^\frac12}}}\to \left|{{\frac{1}{x-1}}}\right|$$

therefore the series converges for

$$\left|{{\frac{1}{x-1}}}\right|<1 \iff|x-1|>1 \iff x-1<-1 \lor x-1>1 \iff x<0 \lor x>2$$

More in detail we have that

- for $x>2 \implies x-1>1$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\frac{1}{(x-1)^n\sqrt{n+5}}}$$

which converges for example by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac 1 {n^2}$.

- for $x=2$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+5}}}$$

which diverges.

- for $1<x<2 \implies 0<x-1<1$ by $y=\frac 1{x-1}>1$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\frac{y^n}{\sqrt{n+5}}}$$

which diverges.

- for $x=0$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+5}}}$$

which converges by alternating series test.

- for $0<x<1 \implies 0<1-x<1$ by $y=\frac 1{1-x}>1$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\frac{y^n(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+5}}}$$

which diverges.

- for $x<0 \implies 1-x>1$

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{\frac{(-1)^n}{(1-x)^n\sqrt{n+5}}}$$

which converges by alternating series test.

Comment: For $x = 3/2,$ the first series *diverges*. Actually, it is so for all $x \in [1,2].$

Comment: Opsss of course I fix that thanks!

Comment: Thanks, why is it $x>2$ or $x-1>1$?

Comment: @Cesare We are considering all the cases here excluding only the case $x=1$.

Comment: I still don't get why you have considered $x-1>1$ instead of $x-1>0$.

Comment: @Cesare I add something also by your derivation by root test.

Comment: Thanks, in the first part, $\left|{{\frac{1}{(x-1)}}}\right|{{\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(n+5)^2}}}}\to \left|{{\frac{1}{(x-1)}}}\right|$ I'm not sure what you did there. You put the root outside of the absolute value? Why is it power 2? $(n+2)^2$ I think it should be $(n+2)^{1/2}$

Comment: @Cesare Recall that $\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(n+5)^2}}>0$ therefore we can factor out that term (even if not strictly necessary). Moreover recall that $(\sqrt[n]{a})^2=a^{\frac 2 n}=\sqrt[n]{a^2}$.

Comment: Thanks, why is it power of $2$ in the first place though?

Comment: @Cesare Opsss sorry you are absolutely right on that, it was a typo which I carried out. But it doesn't change anything in the derivation. I fix that!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sqrt[2n]{n+5}$ = $\left(\sqrt[n]{n+5}\right)^{1/2}.$

Comment: Thanks, I see. I think I definitely need a little bit more help with this because after seeing this, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The ratio test might be easier: what is

$$\frac1{|x-1|}\sqrt{\frac{n+6}{n+5}}\,?$$